# Alternative to Java Enum

Tags: java

I have an Enum that handles columns in a table.  It is in production.

```
public enum Column {

    NAME("m_Name", "Name", "TEXT"), ADDRESS("m_Address", "Address", "TEXT");

    private String value;
    private String label;
    private String sortType;

    private Column(String value, String label, String sortType) {
        this.setValue(value);
        this.setLabel(label);
        this.setSortType(sortType);
    }
}
```

I now need to add custom columns that I will need to be dynamic.  I realise that I can't make enums dynamic.  What is the alternative?

Comment: try `HashMap` to set `key` and its `value`.

Comment: Just implement it as a class? With a list of columns?

Comment: Just edited to show the sortType property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you adjust `Column` to implement an `interface` and instead of using `Column` elsewhere use the `interface` you can then grow dynamic columns using an ordinary class.

```
interface DbColumn {

    String getLabel();

    String getValue();
}

public enum Column implements DbColumn {

    NAME("m_Name", "Name"), ADDRESS("m_Address", "Address");

    private final String value;
    private final String label;

    private Column(String value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class DynamicColumn implements DbColumn {

    private final String value;
    private final String label;

    private DynamicColumn(String value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  Very new to java.